# Ajax jquery(post) doesn't pass data to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass data to my php page:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['goal']) && isset($_POST['amount'])){


    $goal = $_POST['goal'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];



    $array = array(
      "goal" => $goal,
      "amount" => $amount

    );
    echo json_encode($array);


}
```

However as a result of var_dump $_POST I keep getting an empty array, for some reason my ajax doesn't pass the neccessary data. I tried console.logging the value of fields that I am using and their value is correct it's just that data doesn't pass on the php page.

ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //use button click event
                $("#goalBTN").click(function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let amount = $("#amount").val();
                    let goal = $("#goal_name").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "target-modal-code.php",
                        data:JSON.stringify( {
                                amount: amount,
                                goal: goal
                            }),
                        contentType:"application/json",
                        success: function (response){
                            $("#response").text(response);
                            console.log(amount);
                            console.log(goal);
                        },
                        error: function(response) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                        }
                    })
                });
            });

        </script>
```

And my form is inside a modal :

```
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="enrollLabel">Change your goal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <form action="target-modal-code.php" name="target-form" id="target-form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                                <label for="amount">Cost</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount"
                                       placeholder="Amount">
                                <small class="message" id="message-password"></small>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                                <label for="goal_name">Goal</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal_name" name="goal_name"
                                       placeholder="Goal">
                                <small class="message" id="message-password"></small>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <p class="response" id="response"></p>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="response">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="goalBTN" class="btn btn-warning">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You dont need to convert data into json string, just set `data: {amount: amount, goal: goal}` in ajax request

Comment: try this `data : {amount: amount,goal: goal},`

Comment: @designer132 Sorry it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh Since your answer is the same it didn't fix the issue post still shwos an empty array

Comment: hmmm the rest of the code looks correct, try temporarily remove the line `contentType:"application/json",`

Comment: @JanoszКрајишник  what's the error showing in the browser console when you hit the form submit button

Comment: @designer132 Thank you very much you have fixed it I just commented what you said to comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer after some live testing with Network tab in firefox web dev tools**

The problem is that the current ajax code is not sending any of the elements because of wrong content-type. Let it detect content-type automatically. For jq ajax, default seems to be `contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` even if you don't provide it specifically.

So, this worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //use button click event
            $("#goalBTN").click(function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                // let amount = $("#amount").val();
                // let goal = $("#goal_name").val();

                var formData = {
                  amount: $("#amount").val(),
                  goal_name: $("#goal_name").val(),
                };

                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "target-modal-code.php",
                    // datatype:"json",
                    //data:JSON.stringify(formData),
                    data: formData,
                    //contentType:"application/json",
                    //encode: true,
                    success: function (response){
                        $("#response").text(response);
                        // console.log(amount);
                        // console.log(goal);
                        console.log(formData);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                })
            });
        });

    </script>
```

After little bit of fiddling, I noticed that it works if you DON'T provide it `contentType` at all. Otherwise, AJAX won't send GET or POST params to the server.... dont know why. I know it's weird but that's how it is in jquery ajax.

I have intentionally kept the comments for you to see what all I have tried.

So to summarize,

- Don't stringify the form data,
- Don't provide contentType to ajax
  request.

Cheers.!

Comment: Updated the answer after fiddling with it.

Comment: contentType:"application/json", -- This line took my few hours. after removing it php receives data.

Answer (score 0):

format send ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : {
        foo : 'bar',
        bar : 'foo'
    },
    ...
});
```

in your case: change data send format like:

```
data: {
   amount: amount,
   goal: goal
}
```

Comment: I tried to send it like this and other people commented the same thing but it still doesn't work